# SQL Server filter by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have query which returns me results about sales made overall, but now I want to filter them by adding `DATE` interval.

EDIT: `fs.DateKey` is of `DateTime` datatype

My original query:

```
SELECT s.storekey, 
       e.employeekey, 
       e.parentemployeekey, 
       pc.productcategorykey, 
       pc.productcategoryname, 
       Sum(fs.salesamount)AS SalesAmount 
FROM   dimstore s 
       INNER JOIN factsales fs 
               ON fs.storekey = s.storekey 
       RIGHT JOIN dimemployee e 
               ON e.employeekey = s.storemanager 
       INNER JOIN dimproduct p 
               ON p.productkey = fs.productkey 
       INNER JOIN dimproductsubcategory psc 
               ON psc.productsubcategorykey = p.productsubcategorykey 
       INNER JOIN dimproductcategory pc 
               ON pc.productcategorykey = psc.productcategorykey 
GROUP  BY s.storekey, 
          e.employeekey, 
          e.parentemployeekey, 
          pc.productcategoryname, 
          pc.productcategorykey 
ORDER  BY employeekey
```

I was thinking to add `WHERE fs.DateKey BETWEEN '2007-01-20' AND '2007-01-25'` but for some reason results are incorrect. I can't understand why. Any tips or suggestions how I can achieve desired results?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all, what data type is `fs.DateKey`?, and what do you mean with incorrect results?

Comment: @Lamak The second part of your comment is missing a "Second of all"

Comment: WHy do you have a RIGHT JOIN?

Comment: I would advise you to first try selecting records from fs using the where clause you specified, then adding the other tables in until you see the data disappear. Then you will have found the "problem"

Comment: The problem in GROUP BY statement. Without group by it does all filtering well, but after I apply it results are unrealistic.

Comment: Also please use `'YYYYMMDD'` for date literals, without the dashes. And using `BETWEEN`, do you expect all rows from January 25th, or only those with a time of exactly midnight? Please read https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: What the heck does "unrealistic" mean? Maybe create a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) so we aren't all guessing about your vague problems.

Comment: What do you mean by "incorrect"???? What are you getting? What are you expecting?

Comment: Why is almost every answer to this question a perfect example of speak first, read/think later?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Think of the rep!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Posting as an answer, because I have a LOT of comments:

The `RIGHT JOIN` is certainly wrong.  This would imply that some stores do not need to exist, but of course, your sales facts are tied to stores with an `INNER JOIN`.  It is effectively being turned into an `INNER JOIN` anyway, so is unlikely to be the source of your issues.

The fact that you used a `RIGHT JOIN` tells me that you think there could be a case where a foreign key is optional in some of the facts or dimensions.  I'd like to know why this is.

In any case, in a straightforward star model, you usually only see `INNER JOIN`s and sometimes `LEFT JOINs`.

Because the fact table is at the center of the star, I would usually list that first in the `SELECT`, especially if there are `LEFT JOIN`s out from the fact table.

Since it is a datawarehouse, and you probably have a lot of data, I'm not sure how much you can post so we can understand your expectations versus the results you are getting, but be aware that using `BETWEEN` includes both endpoints and that `DATETIME` datatype can contain a time portion.  Because of this, I almost always prefer to use the notation `dt >= start_date AND dt < end_date`.  It's typically no performance difference, since `BETWEEN` is basically syntactic sugar for `dt >= start_date AND dt <= end_date`.

Comment: Well, sorry to continue being pedantic, but `BETWEEN` is syntactic sugar for `>= and <=` not `>= and <`.

Comment: to elaborate, if `end_date` is `2007-01-25` then do `dt < '20070126'` (assuming `YYYYMMDD` because there isn't really a 26th month).

Comment: Thank for everyone how posted a comments and tips. Specially for `RIGHT JOIN`. I think I just get confused, looks like my query produces correct results and my expectations were wrong. Sorry I've confused you.

Comment: Okay so now let's all please vote to close as "waste of everyone's time."

Comment: @AaronBertrand Sorry, yes, of course, I pointed out it includes both endpoints, but then got sloppy at the end.  BETWEEN is of course syntactic sugar for the expression where the inequalities include both endpoints.